# Authorize React Components for Users by Role/Permissions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, authorization

I made a SPA with React and ASP .Net Core.
The Authentication is done via Bearer-Tokens (using IdentityServer4 and oidc-client) and Authorization is done on the Server Side (using PolicyServer).

Sofar I can:

- Authenticate my User from React by redirecting him to my
  IdentityServer-Login Page.
- Authorize my logged in User to use my Rest-Api, only if he has the required
  Role/Permission from PolicyServer. Using axios to access the Rest-Api works without any problems too.

In my App after logging in, there are multiple Buttons visible, clicking them opens a Component.
My Problem is: I cant find a good way to authorize Users the access to these Components, after pressing a Button.

I need to check if the User has the required Role/Permission or alternatively Claims.

After not finding any way to do this I thought about using axios to check a HttpGet which returns if User is authorized or not.
But having an axios-command on client-side is very likely not an good way.

Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally use HOC(Higer Order Component)/Wrapper for authorization for routes.

**What does HOC does?**

- We pass the required component for respective route to HOC and additional data required. In route's `component` prop pass HOC as `component={WithAuthorization(MyComponent,miscData) />`
- It allows us to render component conditionally. In a nutshell **if authorization logic fails, then render fallback Component or render the actual component passed to it**

My typical HOC would look like:

```
export const WithAuthorization = (Component, menuObj) => {
    /* For route's data, you can have menu's metadata */
    const { menuId, action, menuName } = menuObj;
    class UserMode extends React.Component {
        state = {
            isAllowedToAccess: false,
            isProcessCompleted: false,
            menuPermissionObj: {},
            masterAccess: false
        };

        async componentDidMount() {
            const permission = this.props.auth.menuPermissions
                ? this.props.auth.menuPermissions
                : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('menu_permissions'));
            await this.checkAuthorization(permission);
        }

        shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
            /* 
            Restrict re-render until there is 
            menuPermissions object available for user profile
            */
            if (this.props.auth.menuPermissions) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        /* Business logic to check roles & permissions for the user and restrict them */
        checkAuthorization = permissionArr => {
            let access = false;
            let menuPermissionObj = {};

            /* PERFORM YOUR BUSINESS LOGIC HERE */
            function apiCall(){
            /* return true or false */
            }
            access = apiCall(); // either true or false depending on API call

            console.log('has access', access);
            this.setState({
                isAllowedToAccess: access,
                isProcessCompleted: true,
                menuPermissionObj
            });
        };

        render() {
            const {
                isProcessCompleted,
                isAllowedToAccess,
                menuPermissionObj,
                masterAccess
            } = this.state;
            return isProcessCompleted ? (
                isAllowedToAccess ? (
                    <Fragment>
                        <Component
                            {...this.props}
                            menuAccess={menuPermissionObj}
                            masterAccess={masterAccess}
                        />
                    </Fragment>
                ) : (
                    <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
                )
            ) : (
                <Loading state={this.state} />
            );
        }
    }

    /* OPTIONAL: Use react-redux's connect if you want to access redux's store data */

    return UserMode;
};
```

Comment: I used your approach, but iam not quite satisfied tbh, inside "checkAuthorization" iam using axios to get if the User has the Permission from menuObj inside the Database. Is it possible to change Values (like the returning bool from false to true) inside the Web Debugger? I tried it out but didnt manage to, but i do not know if its easily bypassed.

Comment: Bypass API from wrapper. Call it from main `App.js` and it will store data in redux either if you pass it to wrapper.

Comment: You wrote - `like the returning bool from false to true)` What does this imply ? Do you want to eliminate `shouldComponentUpdate()` lifecycle process?

Comment: No, i meant that in "checkAuthorization" i set the "access"-Value from the result of my "axios"-Query.

Comment: Yes, that's why I have written in comment as : "Write your business logic", which will eventually calculate `access` as result of either `true` or `false`

Comment: That's why I have left checkAuthorization middle part empty as your `access` value will be calculated from axios call or any side effect. **I have updated the answer**

Comment: Thanks, your answer and comments were the most helpful so I accepted your answer. Iam not completely satisfied because Iam unsure if there are any security issues this way, but I think I will open another question later (because I lack the knowledge in that topic). :)

Comment: So glad to provide assist for the problem. Got your perception, alright then!

Answer (score 1):

Using IdentityServer and .Net Core identity, you can do the following:

1. Add the role to the token meaning insert a role claim to the issued claims by registering a transient service in Startup.cs.
2. Now when you call the user.profile in AuthorizeService.js you will notice the added property "role", all you have to do now is to validate and render your component based on that role/permission.
3. Let us say you need to only give 'Member' access to a certain component:

   ```
    export class NavMenu extends Component {
   static displayName = NavMenu.name;

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.toggleNavbar = this.toggleNavbar.bind(this);
        this.state = {
          collapsed: true,
          isAuthenticated: false,
          role: null,
        };
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        this._subscription = authService.subscribe(() => this.populateState());
        this.populateState();
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        authService.unsubscribe(this._subscription);
      }
      async populateState() {
        const [isAuthenticated, user] = await Promise.all([
          authService.isAuthenticated(),
          authService.getUser(),
        ]);
        this.setState({
          isAuthenticated,
          role: user && user.role,
        });
      }

      toggleNavbar() {
        this.setState({
          collapsed: !this.state.collapsed,
        });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <header>
            <Navbar
              className="navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm ng-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3"
              light
            >
              <Container>
                <NavbarBrand tag={Link} to="/">
                  SPA.Utility.Templates
                </NavbarBrand>
                <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggleNavbar} className="mr-2" />
                <Collapse
                  className="d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse"
                  isOpen={!this.state.collapsed}
                  navbar
                >
                  <ul className="navbar-nav flex-grow">
                    <NavItem>
                      <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-dark" to="/">
                        Home
                      </NavLink>
                    </NavItem>

                    {this.state.role && this.state.role.includes("Member") ? (
                      <NavItem>
                        <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-dark" to="/counter">
                          Counter
                        </NavLink>
                      </NavItem>
                    ) : null}
                    <NavItem>
                      <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-dark" to="/fetch-data">
                        Fetch data
                      </NavLink>
                    </NavItem>

                    <LoginMenu></LoginMenu>
                  </ul>
                </Collapse>
              </Container>
            </Navbar>
          </header>
        );
      }
    }
   ```

notice the part when you render a whole component depending on the role of the user:

```
{this.state.role && this.state.role.includes("Member") ? (
               <NavItem>
                 <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-dark" to="/counter">
                   Counter
                 </NavLink>
               </NavItem>
             ) : null}
```

Here is a sample application using RBAC in .Net core3.1 and reactJs that might help you: https://github.com/HoussemMereghni/SPA-NetCore-React-RBAC

Answer (score 0):

You can setup protected routes using react router. Check https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/ for more info.